# At what speed should the ferry be operated in order to minimise the cost per kilometre?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A ferry operator wishes to minimise the *cost per unit distance travelled* of operating the ferry. When the ferry is travelling at speed *v* km $h^{-1}$, the cost in fuel per hour is $\dfrac {v^3}{10}$ dollars. The other costs of running the ferry (wages, maintenance, *etc.*) are $675 per hour. At what speed should the ferry be operated in order to minimise the cost per kilometre?

So for this question, I think that we first have to find a function for *'cost per unit distance'*. So if ***C*** is the cost, ***t*** is the time in units of hours and ***d*** is the distance, then $\dfrac {dC}{dd}$ would be the *'cost per unit distance'*. From the question, *'cost in fuel per hour'* is given by $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ = $\dfrac {v^3}{10}$, and *'other costs'* is $\dfrac{dC}{dt}$ = $675$. So $\dfrac{dC}{dd}$ = $\dfrac {dv}{dt}$ $\times$ $\dfrac {dC}{dt}$, therefore $\dfrac {dC}{dd}$ = $\dfrac {v^3}{10}$ $\times$ $675$. Then to minimise the speed, find the second derivative of *'cost per unit distance travelled'* and find the *speed*. But I don't know if my setting of the given values are correct.

Comment: Using $d$ as a variable when you are going to take derivatives is an invitation to mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are working in km and hours, we may as well take the unit distance as $1$ km.  When we are traveling at speed $v$, it takes $\frac 1v$ hour to travel $1$ km.  The cost for fuel is then $\frac 1v \cdot \frac {v^3}{10}=\frac {v^2}{10}$ per km.  The cost for crew is $\frac 1v \cdot 675=\frac {675}v$ per km.  The total cost is $\frac {v^2}{10}+\frac {675}v$.  Now take the derivative, set to zero...